# Find top category parent and add child below respective parent in sample JSON using java

Tags: java, json

I found this sample eCommerce JSON. I wanted to arrange this JSON in hierarchically.

You can find this JSON file on below URL.

https://stark-spire-93433.herokuapp.com/json

I wanted to arrange this JSON in the following manner.

```
Mens Wear
    |Bottom Wear
        |Jeans
        |Tracks & Trousers
    |Foot Wear
        |Casuals
        |Formals
    |Upper Wear
        |Shirts
        |T-Shirts
Electronics
    |Mobiles
        |Apple
        |Samsung
    |Laptops
        |Dell
        |Toshiba
```

All variants will go under the last hierarchy of products. For example Dell, Apple, Shirts and so on.

I have created model classes for this JSON.

```
public class Data {
    public ArrayList<Category> categories;
    public ArrayList<Rank> rankings;
}

public class Category {
    public int id;
    public String name;
    public ArrayList<Product> products;
    public ArrayList<Integer> child_categories;
}

public class Rank {
    public String ranking;
    public ArrayList<Product> products;
}

public class Product {
    public int id;
    public String name;
    public String date_added;
    public ArrayList<Variant> variants;
    public Tax tax;
    public int view_count;
    public int order_count;
    public int shares;
}

public class Tax {
    public String name;
    public double value;
}

public class Variant {
    public int id;
    public String color;
    //in some variants size is null eg. mobiles, if null pass 0.
    public int size;
    public double price;
}
```

Now I don't understand how should I start.

Comment: I'd suggest do don't use any object mapping. I'd prepare a few classes to present the tree structure you want, like if you'd need to build the tree programmatically. For example, your Category shouldn't contain ArrayList<Integer> child_categories, but ArrayList<Category> children instead... After that, use a stream oriented parsing https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-streaming-api and build you tree walking through JSON tokens as you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution

### Outline

1. modify the class model from the post - add tree structure using [Composite design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern)
2. deserialize the json into the class model from the post using Jackson library.
3. build a `Map<Integer, Category>` that allows direct access to category by its id
4. iterate over the categories, for each one, iterate over its children, for each child id, get the child category from the map and assign as child instance
5. finally, iterate over the tree using [depth first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) and print the categories using [visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern)

### Data Structure

I took your model and modified a little bit:

1. Changed lists to be defined as the interface. this is since the variable construction is performed by the json deserializer that may decide to use a different implementation of `List`
2. Added collections for the implementation of Composite pattern: each `Category` has list of child categories as `Category` instances, `Data` was added list of tree roots.
3. Changed variable names to better reflect purpose and usage.

Here is how the modified `Data` and `Category` classes look like:

```
public class Category
{
    public int id;
    public String name;
    public List<Product> products;
    @JsonProperty("child_categories")
    public List<Integer> childCategoryIds;

    // tree-structure properties
    public boolean isRoot = true;
    public List<Category> childCategories = new ArrayList<>();

    public void visit(Visitor<Category> visitor, int level) {
        visitor.accpet(this, level);
        childCategories.forEach(cat -> cat.visit(visitor, level + 1));
    }
}

public class Data
{
    public List<Category> categories;
    public List<Rank> rankings;

    // tree-structure properties
    public List<Category> tree;

    // initiate traversal of each root withj printer visitor
    public void printTree() {
        Visitor<Category> printer = new Printer();
        tree.forEach(root -> root.visit(printer, 0));
    }
}
```

### Solution Implementation

**Visitor Pattern**

```
// visitor interface
public interface Visitor<T>
{
    /**
     * @param level 0 is root, 1 root's child and so on
     */
    public void accpet(T node, int level);
}

// printer visitor: prints to console each visited category, properly indented 
public class Printer implements Visitor<Category>
{
    @Override
    public void accpet(Category node, int level) {
        System.out.println(indentByLevel(level) + node.id + " " + node.name);
        // in case of category with products - print them and variants
        if (node.products != null  &&  !node.products.isEmpty()) {
            printProducts(node, level);
        }
    }

    private void printProducts(Category node, int level) {
        node.products.forEach(product -> {
            System.out.println(indentByLevel(level+1) + product.id + " " + product.name);
            if (product.variants != null  &&  !product.variants.isEmpty()) {
                product.variants.forEach(variant -> {
                    System.out.println(indentByLevel(level+2) + variant.id + " " + variant.color);
                });
            }
        });
    }

    private static final String levelIndent = "    ";
    private String indentByLevel(int level) {
        if (level > 0) {
            return String.join("", Collections.nCopies(level, levelIndent));
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

**Main class**

```
public class JsonToTree
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Data data = readJson("https://stark-spire-93433.herokuapp.com/json");
            jsonToTree(data);
            data.printTree();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // read and parse source to Data object
    // using java 11 HttpURLConnection and Jackson ObjectMapper
    public static Data readJson(String url) throws IOException {
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        try (InputStream responseStream = connection.getInputStream()) {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
             return mapper.readValue(responseStream, Data.class);
        }
    }

    public static void jsonToTree(Data data) {
        // populate array of categories. array index is category id
        // this will allow random access to category by its id
        Map<Integer, Category> categoryById = data.categories.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(cat -> cat.id, Function.identity(), (cat1, cat2) -> cat1));

        // populate list of category objects for each category according to list of child ids
        // along the way, mark each child category as not root
        data.categories.stream()
            .filter(cat -> cat.childCategoryIds != null  &&  !cat.childCategoryIds.isEmpty())
            .forEach(catWithChildren ->
                catWithChildren.childCategoryIds.forEach(id -> {
                    Category child = categoryById.get(id);
                    if (child != null) {
                        catWithChildren.childCategories.add(child);
                        child.isRoot = false;
                    }
                })
            );

        // build tree in data from root categories
        data.tree = new ArrayList<>();
        data.categories.stream()
            .filter(cat -> cat.isRoot)
            .forEach(root -> data.tree.add(root));
    }
}
```

### Printout

```
3 Mens Wear
    4 Bottom Wear
        2 Jeans
            3 Spykar Denim
                9 Blue
                10 Black
                11 Blue
                12 Blue
            4 Lee Cotton Jeans
                13 Blue
                14 Black
                15 White
                16 Black
            24 Denim Wash
                71 Blue
                72 Grey
            25 Pepe Jeans Slim Fit
                73 Blue
                74 Light Blue
            26 Spykar Funky Regular
                75 Blue
                76 Black
        8 Tracks & Trousers
            7 Comfort Tracks
                25 Blue
                26 Red
                27 White
                28 Red
            8 Adidas Trousers
                29 White
                30 Yellow
                31 Green
                32 Red
            30 Superdry track
                83 Red
                84 Blue
            31 Night Comfy Track
                85 Red
                86 Black
            32 Superdry Joggers
                87 Red
                88 Blue
    5 Foot Wear
        1  Casuals
            1 Nike Sneakers
                1 Blue
                2 Red
                3 Blue
                4 Red
            2 Adidas Running Shoes
                5 White
                6 Black
                7 White
                8 Red
            21 Roadster Loafers
                65 Black
                66 Blue
            22 Light Loafers
                67 Blue
                68 Yellow
            23 Floaters
                69 Black
                70 Red
        9 Formals
            9 Bata Lace up Shoes
                33 Black
                34 Brown
                35 Black
                36 Brown
            10 Franco Leather
                37 Black
                38 Brown
                39 Black
                40 Brown
    6 Upper Wear
        7 T-Shirts
            5 Polo Collar T-Shirt
                17 Blue
                18 Red
                19 White
                20 Red
            6 Adidas Nylon
                21 White
                22 Yellow
                23 Green
                24 Red
            27 Being Human Collar T-shirt
                77 Blue
                78 Black
            28 V - Neck Smart T-Shirt
                79 Blue
                80 Black
            29 Manchester United
                81 Red
                82 Red
        10 Shirts
            11 Wrangler Checked Shirt
                41 Blue
                42 Red
                43 Black
                44 White
            12 Printed Shirt
                45 Blue
                46 Black
                47 Red
                48 Brown
11 Electronics
    12 Mobiles
        14 Apple
            13 Iphone 6S
                49 Silver
                50 Golden
            14 Iphone 7
                51 Black
                52 Silver
            33 Iphone 6
                89 Silver
                90 Golden
            34 Iphone 6s Plus
                91 Silver
                92 Golden
            35 Iphone 7 Plus
                93 Black
                94 Grey
        15 Samsung
            15 Galaxy S7 Edge
                53 Black
                54 White
            16 Galaxy J5
                55 Black
                56 White
            36 Galaxy J7
                95 Black
                96 White
            37 Galaxy Grand Prime
                97 Black
                98 White
            38 Note 4
                99 Black
                100 White
    13 Laptops
        16 Dell
            17 Dell Inspiron Core
                57 Black
                58 Red
            18 Dell Inspiron 11
                59 Black
                60 Red
        17 Toshiba
            19 Satellite Pro
                61 Black
                62 Red
            20 Satellite P50
                63 Black
                64 Red
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem is the usage of indirect references to child-categories using ids. The goal would be to transform the indirect references to direct references such as something like `data.getCategory().getChildCategory().getName()` is possible.

I would solve this by introducing two abstraction layers:

The first one exists only for deserialization. The classes - let's call them `JsonBean`s - of this layer would closely resemble the structure of the json, so the child-categories are only numbers. This also has the advantage that the `JsonBean`s could contain special annotations for deserialization like they are used by `Jackson`.

The second layer will be the object graph that is used in the application and it replaces the child-categories with concrete objects. Let's simply call this type of classes `Bean`. The `Bean`s would be independent from the design of the JSON, in such a way, that they could be reused even if the data is loaded from a database instead of a JSON.

The deserialization process would then have two steps: First the raw deserialization into `JsonBean`s. Then followed by a transformation service that would copy the `JsonBean`s to the application `Bean`s. This transformation would then resolve the ids of the child-categories to concrete `Category`-objects.

The separation between the pure value model and the persistence model also gives some safety in case the JSON's structure is changed in the future. As long as the change is not too severe, this would have little effect on your application, since you would only need to change the `JsonBean`s and the transformation - not everything else that uses the data after the deserialization.